# Coldfusion 2018 Administration pages running very slow

Tags: performance, iis, coldfusion, cfml

I have a CF2018 server that is running via IIS.  The website it is server runs and responds fine. However after a few days of running the CFADMIN pages start to run really slow.  Logging in to CFADMIN can take minutes and navigating between pages can take minutes as well. The website itself continues to respond fine though.
Anyone every see this before? Have a fix?  At least know where to start debugging

Comment: This should probably be better asked on https://serverfault.com/ since it's not a programming issue. But you'll get better responses on the CFML Slack Workspace. There are vastly more CF Admins there than here. You can sign up here if you aren't already. https://cfml-slack.herokuapp.com/ Personally, I've never seen CF Admin run slowly if the applications aren't also running slowly. You should be on the instance of the CF server, different application spaces. Does the problem go away if you restart the service? May need to allocate more memory to the server instance.

Comment: You can try to enable compression and output caching, then check whether the cfadmin pages are still running slowly, if it is still slow, you can refer to this link to troubleshoot: [Troubleshooting IIS Performance Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-iis-performance-issues-or-application-errors-using-logparser).